# P tag jiggling when incrementing/decrementing number

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm having a problem with my code. I have a simple increment decrement app. The value is wrapped in a p tag, the problem is when I increment/decrement the p tag keeps jiggling like it's trying to make space for itself even tho I already tried giving it more width.
Thanks in advance! :)

Stitches.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import './scss/Stitches.scss'

export const Stitches = ({ stitches, addStitches, removeStitches, resetStitches }) => {
return (
    <div className='stitches-wrapper'>
        <div className="stitch-count">
            <p>Stitches: {stitches}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="buttons-div">
            <button onClick={addStitches}>Add</button>
            <button onClick={removeStitches}>Remove</button>
            <button onClick={resetStitches}>Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 )
}
```

Stitches.scss:

```
.stitches-wrapper {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
margin-top: 20px;
width: 100%;

.stitch-count {
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 8px;

    p {
        text-align: center;
        outline: 1px solid red;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.buttons-div {
    width: 60%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    button {
        padding: 8px;
        margin-left: 8px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 8px;
        font-size: 14px;
        background-color: config.$primary-color;
    }
}
```